# Painfully slow to browse large list of subfolders via SMB and/or AFP

Tags: file-sharing, nas, afp, smb

Having an issue where I have a folder on a QNAP NAS with over 68,000 subfolders within it.

**I can browse it quickly and almost instantaneously within Windows 7 via SMB, however in OSX 10.6.8 and 10.7.2, it takes nearly 10+ minutes to display the subfolders, using both SMB and AFP.**

Hoping there is an easy solution - we can't break the folders into smaller subfolders due to a requirement of proprietary software that accesses the sub folders.

I've tried the fixes suggested here, which don't seem to help: http://www.macwindows.com/snowleopard-filesharing.html#030311b

**Have the same issue browsing the files on a Windows 2003 server, so it is not a NAS issue - rather, it's an issue with how OS X browses over the network.  *Perhaps it is trying to cache all the files/folders before displaying them?***

Windows 7 doesn't do this, and therefore the subfolders display almost immediately.

Comment: What version of the QNAP firmware are you running? The latest firmware has some good fixes for AFP specifically. I've noticed significant increase in speed of access.

Comment: Thanks - forgot to mention that I'm running the latest v3.5.1 Build1002

Comment: Hmm I've got the same firmware and its working fine. Are you able to ssh to it and see if anything is chewing processes ?

Comment: Have you ever solved this issue? This has been bugging me from day one.

Comment: @AronRotteveel nope, still appears to be an ongoing problem.

Comment: Here we are, six years and eight months later and this is still a problem. I gather no one here has ever found a solution?

Comment: Still no solutions to this sadly. I can add though that if I try to browse my SMB shares in a terminal window, even `ls` takes way, way too long to execute. So it's not the Finder specifically, but rather a system-wide problem. I wonder if this has something to do with macOS trying to read extended attributes of files, or something else like that that's mac specific?

Answer (score 1):

I, too, find this a pain with my QNAP box. FYI the firmware has now been updated to 3.6.0 released just a few days ago, and there is some noticeable improvement with the update. However, you may consider using the iSCSI feature among the QNAP settings to make the file shares appear as a hard drive showing up on your desktop for better speed. I've noticed iSCSI works better IMO if your connection to the QNAP is hardwired throughout and not wireless in any way; wireless iSCSI works, just not as fast in my experience.

Answer (score -1):

try to relaunch your finder, some of my colleagues got improve after this.
if in same lan, some computer fast and some slow.

Comment: Can you add some detail on how Finder can be relaunched without logout/login?